# How to clear DataGridView in C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I used `MS-Access` to fill `DataGridView` in my `C#` Windows Form Application. When i query datas from Access database it displays correctly. But when i press the view data button again it adds empty columns. This process repeats. I used

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

to clear `DataGridView` but no luck.

Comment: What about `dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();`?

Comment: If your DataGridView is bounded, "dataGridView1.DataSource = null" is sufficient to clear it. If you want to Refresh it after a new fill, set the DataSource to null and restore it to what it was before, i.e. DataTable or BindingSource.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();` worked thanks. @Equalsk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments on the original question:

Try clearing the columns as well

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also clear what the `DataSource` is bound to or do the following:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

See https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/332902/how-to-clear-datagridview-in-csharp

Or,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ca891be5-4f5c-4c70-9123-6cbf7a97c93b/clearing-a-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols